# Equation involving recursive n:th-roots.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, recursion

Inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453348/find-x-such-that-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-dots-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-do/1453381#1453381), replacing square roots with $n$-roots:

$$\sqrt[n]{X+\sqrt[n]{X+\sqrt[n]{X+ \dots}}}  =\sqrt[n]{X\sqrt[n]{X\sqrt[n]{X \dots}}}$$  Then find the $X$ value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically has the same solution: Solve $a=\sqrt[n]{X+a}$ for $a$. This gives you $a^n=a+X$, or $a^n-a=X$.

Now solve $b=\sqrt[n]{Xb}$ for $b$, this gives $b^n=Xb$. Now if we have $a=b$, then we have the following system of equations.

$$a^n-a=X$$

$$a^n=Xa$$

This gives $Xa-a=X$, and hence $X(a-1)=a$, thus $X=\frac{a}{a-1}$.

Now we have $a^n=\frac{a^2}{a-1}$, and hence $a^{n+1}-a^n-a^2=0$. Hence $a=0$ or $a^{n-1}-a^{n-3}-1=0$. The latter equation has no nice solutions unfortunately, but you can approximate them.

Comment: What I find curious is that (if the polynomial is right) among the solutions many are likely to be complex conjugate pairs. So an infinite sequence of scalings and rotations in the complex plane is equal to an infinite sequence of translations and rotations.

Comment: $(n)-(2)=(n-2)$. And since the coefficient sequence has exactly one sign change, there is exactly one positive root. Which can also be seen from the equivalent equation $a^{1-n}+a^{-1}=1$, where the left side is monotonically decreasing (and convex) for $a>0$.